# MFC automatically moves to the next edit Box

Tags: tabs, mfc, dialog, editcontrol

I am creating a simple test program with MFC.
It is a program that sends 1 byte hex value to each of 10 edit control.
I want to automatically move to the next Edit box when 1 byte is entered in the edit control. How can I do this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You can try something like that: PostMessage(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, (WPARAM)hWndCtrl, (LPARAM)TRUE);

Comment: Please elaborate your question, it's not very clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

To advance input focus to the next control, call [CDialog::NextDlgCtrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#nextdlgctrl).

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct answer, I think he wants to move the cursor to the next edit control _"when 1 byte is entered in the edit control"_, whetever that means.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Neither am I, but the only one who can answer that question has gone missing.